# Плывет верстка в адаптивном диапазоне

Tags: css, media-queries, position

Ребята выручайте. В верстке совсем недавно, много не знаю, голова уже кругом. В общем заголовок спозиционирован абсолютно.. Но при адаптиве все съезжало. Пришлось правила все вывести в медиа запрос и каждый раз его переписывать. Вывести то вывел, на всех идеально отображается.. Но на диапазоне 768 - 992px все плывет. Ткните пожалуйста в ошибку...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Все плывет]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-100.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: 100;

}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-300.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: 300;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-500.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: 500;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-700.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: 700;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl-900.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: 900;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl';
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/MuseoSansCyrillic-100Italic.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Museo Sans Cyrl', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#first {
 background: url(../img/header.png) no-repeat center top /cover;
 height: 100vh;
}
header {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 height: 77px;
}
.overlay {
 position: absolute;
 height: 100vh;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgba(79,134,157,1);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79,134,157,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69) 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(79,134,157,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79,134,157,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69) 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79,134,157,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69) 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(79,134,157,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69) 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(79,134,157,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.69) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4f869d', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=1 );
}
ul, li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 display: block;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, p {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
.main_menu_list_item a {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #fff;
}
.main_menu_list_item {
 margin-top: 18px;
 margin-right: 1%;
 padding: 10px;
}
.main_menu_list_item:hover {
 background: #375f73;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
.phone {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
}
.icon {
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.heading h1 {
 font-size: 90px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1.2rem;
}
.heading p {
 font-size: 51px;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1rem;
}
.circyle {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 20%;
 margin-bottom: -22px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -22px;
 border: 1px dashed #fff;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 45px;
 height: 45px;
 text-align: center;
}
.circyle i{
 font-size: 32px;
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 5px;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
 .heading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -176px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .heading h1 {
  font-size: 47px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8rem;
 }
 .heading p {
  font-size: 33px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .heading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -221px;
  text-align: center;
 }
 .heading h1 {
  font-size: 64px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8rem;
 }
 .heading p {
  font-size: 44px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8rem;
 }
}


@media screen and (min-width:  992px) {
 .heading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 37%;
  margin-top: -54px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -315px;
  text-align: center;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
 <title>Болгария ждет Вас</title>
</head>
<body>
 <section id="first">
  <header id="header">
   <nav id="navbar">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-4 col-sm-3">
      <div>
       <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Логотип">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-7 d-none d-lg-block">
      <ul class="main_menu_list d-flex justify-content-center">
       <li class="main_menu_list_item">
        <a href="#">Главная</a>     
       </li>
       <li class="main_menu_list_item">
        <a href="#">О компании</a> 
       </li>
       <li class="main_menu_list_item">
        <a href="#">Недвижимость и переезд</a> 
       </li>
       <li class="main_menu_list_item">
        <a href="#">Контакты</a> 
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-3 d-lg-flex col-sm-6 col-md-5 ml-auto d-sm-flex d-none align-items-center">
      <div class="icon">
       <img src="img/phone.png" alt="icon">
      </div>
      <div class="phone">
       +7 (495) 12-321-345<br>
       +7 (495) 12-321-345
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </nav>
  </header>
   <div class="heading">
    <h1>Болгария</h1>
    <p>ждет вас</p>
   </div>
   <div class="circyle">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
   </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: если мне не изменяет память я вижу впрос связанный с  этой версткой уже 5-ый раз за последнее два дня.Если не умеете гуглить то вы не сможете работать программистом.

Comment: Гуглил.. Увы, ответа не нашел.. Да и чтобы чему то научиться, нужен человек, который покажет ошибку.. Я еще ни один раз напишу по этому макету.. Все с чего то начинают.. Лучше бы помогли ошибку найти, чем критиковать обучающихся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас "дыра" в медиа запросах. Сейчас стили применяются для экранов

`screen < 768px | --- "дя этого части нет стилей" --- | 992px < screen`

Добавьте стили для
`@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 991px)`

Comment: Спасибо, понял..